# Wt C++ error: ‘panel’ does not name a type while using auto

Tags: c++, wt

I am trying to compile a standard example of Wt widget (C++ web toolkit) given here: https://webtoolkit.eu/widgets/layout/grouping-widgets (last example on the page). 
Below is the code:

```
#include <Wt/WAnimation.h>
#include <Wt/WPanel.h>
#include <Wt/WText.h>

auto panel = Wt::cpp14::make_unique<Wt::WPanel>(); 
panel->setTitle("Collapsible panel"); 
panel->addStyleClass("centered-example"); 
panel->setCollapsible(true); 

Wt::WAnimation animation(Wt::AnimationEffect::SlideInFromTop, Wt::TimingFunction::EaseOut, 100); 

panel->setAnimation(animation); 
panel->setCentralWidget(Wt::cpp14::make_unique<Wt::WText>("This panel can be collapsed."));
```

This is the error: ‘panel’ does not name a type 
on compiling with both g++ -std=c++14 and g++ -std=c++11

Comment: Is that the entire error message copy/pasted verbatim? Which line is referred to in the error? Maybe the example left out that the code they show needs to be in a function somewhere.

Comment: (a) What version of GCC are you using? (b) As always, a [mre] please. A snippet that can't be compiled in isolation doesn't tell us much of anything.

Comment: If this is your actual code it needs to be inside a function, only declarations are allowed outside functions

Comment: Entire error message is: 
popup.cpp:5:1: error: ‘panel’ does not name a type
    5 | panel = Wt::cpp14::make_unique<Wt::WPanel>();
for each line containing panel.
gcc version: 9.3.0

Comment: On putting it inside main function, following is the error:
popup.cpp:7:1: error: ‘panel’ was not declared in this scope
    7 | panel = Wt::cpp14::make_unique<Wt::WPanel>();